# Non-MNIST Digit Recognition Pytorch

Tags: pytorch, classification, digits

I'm looking for examples of pytorch being used to classify non-MNIST digits. After hours of searching, it appears the algorithms are against me. Does anyone have a good example? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am posting this as answer since i do not have the rep to comment,

Please view the google street view dataset (SVHN). It is like MNIST but there is much more noise present in the data. Another option for you could be to use GANs and make more images which practically wouldn't have existed before. You could also try your hand at non - english mnist data-sets (though it moves away from your original goal).

Link to SVHN with pytorch: https://github.com/potterhsu/SVHNClassifier-PyTorch

Link to original SVHN: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torchvision/datasets.html#svhn

P.S. You could also try making a dataset on your own! This is quite fun to do.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! This this may actually answer my question.

Basically trying to get the numbers from these images: https://gist.github.com/gumdropsteve/43b8a86538aef04e120eebdd8cd9cc3f and it looks like the SVHNClassifier can do that?

(I should have clarified that it's ok if the model is trained on MNIST, I just need to know how to classify my numbers and couldn't find any examples of similar use.)

**EDIT**: just realized you can't respond yet, feel free to comment on the gist if you can. Thanks.

Comment: Really glad I could help :) And yes it can! That's fine, training on SVHN will be an added bonus!